# Different voltage sources across Vin and DC jack

Tags: arduino-uno, voltage, safety, voltage-protection

So I understand that the USB VBUS circuitry turns off provided there is a high enough vin voltage using the PFET and comparator.

I can see that the DC jack is connected to the Vin pin via a diode. 
However, what is to stop someone from plugging a voltage source across the Vin and at the same time putting across a voltage on the DC jack.

If I incorrectly plugged in a voltage source of a low voltage like a coin cell battery across the V<sub>IN</sub> pin and also powered the device using the 9 V DC jack, wouldn't that then send current through the V<sub>IN</sub> pin and back to the coin cell battery?

Is that what would happen in this instance? And if so then shouldn't there be a design feature to prevent users from damaging it like that? Fool/fail safe?

Comment: Vaguely related [Does USB Host always supply power on VBUS?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/313955/does-usb-host-always-supply-power-on-vbus). Might be interesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> wouldnt that then send current through the Vin pin and back to the coin cell battery? Is that what would happen in this instance?

Yep, that's right.

> shouldn't there be a design feature to prevent users from damaging it like that? Fool/fail safe?

No. VIN can also be VOUT. You can use it to power other things that want a higher voltage.